# Passing operator as a parameter in stored proc while preventing the risk of SQL injection

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have following dynamic query and would like to pass an operator as a parameter but it I get an error

> Incorrect syntax near @ageOperator

In addition, I would like to prevent any SQL injection. I can do concatenation like below but it cause SQL injection.

```
@sWhere = ' WHERE AGE1 ' + @ageOperator + ''' + @age + '''
```

Thank you in advance!

```
DECLARE @age INT, 
        @ageOperator VARCHAR(10), 
        @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @sWhere NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @age = 21
SET @ageOperator = ' = '

SET @sWhere = ' WHERE AGE1 @ageOperator @age '

SET @sSQL = ' SELECT * FROM WEBPM_COPY.DBO.Test1111 ' + @sWhere 

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@age INT, @ageOperator char(10)', @age, @ageOperator;
```

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause doesn't make sense. You need to concatenate the variables into your @sWhere var. Try this `set @sWhere = ' WHERE AGE1 ' + @ageOperator + ''' + @age + '''`

Comment: @RyanWilson Yes, I can concatenate the variables into @ sWhere. But it will cause SQL injection. Therefore, I am looking for parametrizing it instead of concatenation.

Comment: If you are worried about `sql injection` don't allow passing parameters that could be maliciously used inside a dynamic sql statement, or do some kind of validation on the parameters before calling your sp

Comment: can't you simply make it only 1 character long?

Comment: @RyanWilson to prevent sql injection,  thats why I am parametrizing it as above instead of concatenation.

Comment: The only parameters you need to allow are `@age` and `@ageOperator` (which I find kind of suspect) but you can do as Ben said and make it `nvarchar(1)` since you are setting `@sSQL` and `@sWhere` yourself anyways.

Comment: For comparisons, you'd probably want an nvarchar(2) for things like `<>` and `>=`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want this code to execute, you must concatenate the operator to the `@sWhere` variable:

```
set @sWhere = ' WHERE AGE1 '+ @ageOperator +' @age ';
```

However, 10 chars are enough to write `'=1 or 1=1--'` (10 chars exactly) so it's not really sql injection safe.

A better implementation would be accepting a limited set of operators and whitelist it:

```
DECLARE @age INT, 
        @ageOperator VARCHAR(10), 
        @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX), 
        @sWhere NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @age = 21;
SET @ageOperator = ' = ';

IF @ageOperator NOT IN('=', '<=', '>=', '<>') 
    RAISERROR ('Invalid @ageOperator', -1, 1);  

SET @sWhere = ' WHERE AGE1 '+ @ageOperator +' @age ';

SET @sSQL = ' SELECT * FROM WEBPM_COPY.DBO.Test1111 ' + @sWhere ;

EXEC sp_executesql @sSQL, N'@age INT, @ageOperator char(10)', @age, @ageOperator;
```

Comment: +1 I think it's also good to change the name of the parameters slightly to avoid confusion from what's been passed to the proc and what's being used in the dynamic query. e.g EXEC sp_executesql \@sSQL, N'\@_Age int, \@_ageOperator varchar(10)', \@_Age = @Age, \@_ageOperator = \@ageOperator; - edit issues trying to escape the @

Answer (score 1):

You can't parametrize an operator. Accordind to a [sp_executesql parameter description](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Each parameter definition consists of a parameter name and a data type

You can use only valued data as parameters. 
Answering your question I'd suggest you to implement your own logic to check an operator:

```
case @ageOperator when '=' then ... else <invalid case> end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you print out what your `@sSQL` variable is, the result is `SELECT * FROM WEBPM_COPY.DBO.Test1111  WHERE AGE1 @ageOperator @age` so it is literally passing the name of the variable as a string, not its value.  This is where your error message is coming from.

Changing your assignment of `@sWhere` to, for example

`set @sWhere = ' WHERE AGE1 ' + @ageOperator + CAST(@age AS VARCHAR(3))` results in `@sSQL` becoming `SELECT * FROM WEBPM_COPY.DBO.Test1111  WHERE AGE1  = 21`, which is valid syntax.

I'm not sure if this still protects from SQL injection - I believe it should as you can't really do much with 3 characters for 'age', but it resolves the "Incorrect syntax near @ageOperator" error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterize the query, you just have to execute dynamic sql inside your dynamic sql. I used the following query to get your expected results:

```
DECLARE @dSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
        ,@dage INT = 21
        ,@dageOperator VARCHAR(10) = ' = '

SET @dSQL = N'
DECLARE @sSQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
    ,@sWhere NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sWhere = '' WHERE AGE1'' + @ageOperator + CAST(@age AS VARCHAR)
SET @sSQL = '' SELECT * FROM WEBPM_COPY.DBO.Test1111 '' + @sWhere

EXEC(@sSQL)'

EXECUTE sp_executesql @dSQL, N'@age INT, @ageOperator varchar(10)', @dage, @dageOperator;
```

Answer (score 0):

Is dynamic sql necessary? If your issue is really as simple as a conditional operator on an INT range, you should be able to do something like this without resorting to a dynamic command:

```
-- test setup
declare @YourTable table (Id int primary key, Age int);
insert into @YourTable
    select 1, 18 union all
    select 2, 25 union all
    select 3, 40 union all
    select 4, 2;


declare @Age int = 19;
declare @AgeOperator char(1) = '<';


-- option 1: 
-- No need for dynamic sql if you just use conditional filters in the
-- where clause.
select  * 
from    @YourTable
where   (Age > @Age and @ageOperator = '>') or
        (Age < @Age and @ageOperator = '<') or
        (Age = @Age and @ageOperator = '=');



-- option 2: 
-- You may see better performance by calculating the range once and using 
-- it in the query instead of the OR conditions
declare @MinAge int;
declare @MaxAge int;

select @MinAge = case @AgeOperator 
    when '<' then 0 
    when '>' then @Age + 1
    when '=' then @Age 
    else null
end;

select @MaxAge = case @AgeOperator
    when '<' then @Age - 1
    when '>' then 2147483647
    when '=' then @Age
    else null
end;


select * 
from   @YourTable
where  Age >= @MinAge and Age <= @MaxAge;
```